# Empty array when printed

Tags: arrays, assembly, avr, avr-gcc

Im writing some C/asm program for the AVR MCU. Im still learning as I go so I hope I have made some sort of mistake in my code.

I have a buffer `volatile unsigned char  suart_0_rx_buffer[SUART_0_BUF_SIZE+1];` in my C code that I am accessing in my asm code as below. All I want to do is store a byte `s0_Rxbyte` in the buffer and increment the pointer `s0_index` every time. 's0_Rxbyte`  is always a non zero value.

```
suart_0_wr_buf_2:  ldi     s0_z_low, lo8(suart_0_rx_buffer)
                   ldi     s0_temp1, hi8(suart_0_rx_buffer)
                   add     s0_z_low, s0_index
                   adc     s0_z_high,s0_temp1
suart_0_wr_buf_3:  st      Z+, s0_Rxbyte
                   inc     s0_index
                   clr     s0_temp1
                   st      Z, s0_temp1
```

If I try and print the contents in a loop in my C code I am getting absolutely nothing.

I didnt want to attach everything here because it will be cluttered.

So does anyone see any problems with the asm code above ?

Comment: We may need more code. For example, where did you set Z? Where is s0_Rxbyte set? Where is your loop/do you even want to loop? The 5th and 6th lines of your code does exactly what you want however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out in the end. It was a case of a simple error in the assembly code that caused it write an incorrect location in the SRAM.

```
suart_0_wr_buf_2:  clr     s0_temp1
                   ldi     s0_z_low, lo8(suart_0_rx_buffer)
                   ldi     s0_z_high, hi8(suart_0_rx_buffer)
                   add     s0_z_low, s0_index
                   adc     s0_z_high, s0_temp1
suart_0_wr_buf_3:  st      Z+, s0_Rxbyte
                   inc     s0_index
                   st      Z, s0_temp1
```